# Git - get list of files changed in a branch that was merged back

Tags: git

Imagine I create a branch from master like this:

```
git checkout -b changes
```

Now I commit couple changes:

```
touch filea && git add filea && git commit -m "added file a"
touch fileb && git add fileb && git commit -m "added file b"
```

Now I can get list of files changed in that branch in multiple ways, like:

```
git log master..changes --name-only --pretty=format: --
```

So far all is good, however when I merge the changes back:

```
git checkout master && git merge changes
```

the above log command no longer works. Is there any way to get list of changed files in an automated way if the only information I have is the branch name?

**EDIT:** I think I should explain what I mean by "automated way": I run a script, that script gets a branch name as parameter and nothing else. I don't know if the branch was already merged to master or not. I don't know if it was fast forward - all of those are a possibility and the method should work in all those cases. It should get the name of the branch and output all files changed in that branch. Doesn't have to be oneliner, but the simpler the better.

Answer (score 1):

If you recorded the merge, or if the merge was done in your repo within the last month or so, it's easy.

For a recorded (non-"fast-forward") merge,

```
git rev-list --first-parent --merges --ancestry-path branch..master | tail -1
```

will get you the merge from that branch tip, so

```
mastermerge=`git rev-list --first-parent --merges --ancestry-path branch..master|tail -1` \
&& git diff $mastermerge^1..$mastermerge^2
```

works there.

If you did a fastforward merge in the local repo the reflog will show you, do `git reflog master`, find the `merge branch: Fast-forward` entry, and specify the before-and-after commits for that merge as the "parents".

Comment: This is getting closer. I've updated the question with some explanation about what I want to get. The issue I see here is that I'm not sure if the last merge is "my" merge. There is no guarantee of that - and yeah, this can be months old.

In fact it might not be merged at all. But if I can detect that somehow, I can do the `git log master..branch` thing.

Comment: Almost the whole point of branch refs is they're temporary and repo-local. Commits matter.

Answer (score 0):

A revision range like `master..changes` means all the commits that are reachable from `changes` excluding those that are reachable from `master`. After you merge `changes` to `master`, all the commits that are reachable from `changes` are now also reachable from `master`. So now `git log master..changes` outputs nothing.

In your case, you could run `git log master^..changes` instead after the merge to get what you want. This works okay so far, but since I have no idea what you would do next, I can give no more suggestion as a generic solution.

Update: you want to know the changed files, since when? If it's always the last time you run the script, you could add a lightweight tag every time you run the script. Maybe you could add another parameter which tells if a tag is to be added this time. This parameter could be helpful for a test purpose.`git describe --tags changes` can find the latest tag of `changes`. If a tag can be found, you could run `git log <tag>..changes` to find all the changes since last run. And then you could add a new tag to `changes` 's head so next time it starts here. But this is still not a generic solution because your demand is not clear enough.

Comment: The problem is, that master^..changes doesn't work before I merge and even after merge it doesn't work for for fast forward merge.

Comment: @Cezz: a fast forward "merge" is not a merge at all, and thus leaves no record (except for reflogs, which eventually expire).  This is one reason some workflows forbid (some) fast-forward operations.